# How to set a block height with testrpc?

Tags: testrpc

How can one set the block height of testrpc so that a contract can react on the new height.

Concrete problem is that I want to write an automated test that shows that after a certain block number conditional can be executed.

Comment: Do you have to test against the exact block number, or can it be relative? Could you just check that `block2.number - block1.number` is sufficient?

Comment: You could restart `testrpc` and run exactly enough transactions to get to a certain block number, but that seems unrealistic. In the real world you will only be able to control relative block numbers, not exact.

Comment: yes, better to be testrpc agnostic, so that you can run em also on a real node once in a while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since testrpc mines one block per transaction, you could just send transactions until the corrrect block height is reached.

If you're doing automated testing, you can use the `evm_snapshot` and `evm_revert` commands so that you don't need to send the transactions on every test, just once at the beginning.

Comment: Can you share more information on how to set the block height using `evm_snapshot`?